# onPress event triggering ListView Item instead of TabBarIOS Item

Tags: react-native, react-native-listview, tabbarios

I have a react-native app with a scrollable `ListView` of clickable items with `TabBarIOS` at the bottom of the screen. I'm sure you get it but attaching a screenshot in case it helps.

[image: screen shot of page]

For some reason, when I click on the `TabBarIOS.Item` it triggers the clickable item underneath and I'm not sure why.

Posting my render function. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest something I could try I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

```
render() {

if (!this.state.loaded) {
  return this.renderLoadingView();
}

return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <StatusBar
      hidden={true}
      barStyle="light-content"
    />
    <View style={styles.chapterListHeader}>
      <Text style={styles.chapterListTitleText}>Chapters</Text>
      <Image
        style={styles.clutchLogoImage}
        resizeMode="contain"
        source={require('../Assets/Images/clutchLogoSmall.png')}
      />
    </View>
    <ListView
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={this.renderChapter.bind(this)}
      renderFooter={this.renderFooter.bind(this)}
      style={styles.chapterList}
      onEndReached={() => {console.log('end reached')}}
      renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID) => <View key={`${sectionID}-${rowID}`} style={styles.separator} />}
    />

    <View>
      <View>

        <TabBarIOS>
          <TabBarIOS.Item
             systemIcon="history"
             selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tabOne'}
             onPress={() => this.setTab('tabOne')}
           ></TabBarIOS.Item>

          <TabBarIOS.Item
             systemIcon="bookmarks"
             selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tabTwo'}
             onPress={() => this.setTab('tabTwo')}
             ></TabBarIOS.Item>

          <TabBarIOS.Item
             systemIcon="more"
             selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'tabThree'}
             onPress={() => this.setTab('tabThree')}
             ></TabBarIOS.Item>
        </TabBarIOS>
      </View>
    </View>

  </View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making your `ListView` the height of the parent `View` minus the height of your `TabBar` ? This will prevent the last item in the `ListView` from being hidden under the `TabBar` component.